# Member functions in classes

Tags: c++

Can a member function in class have a return type of another class?

```
class A
{
    int a,b;
public:
    B func(int x); // func returns type B which is another class
};

class B
{
};
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? (But yes, it is allowed)

Comment: Forget class, you can even return typename as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return any valid type and if that type allows that, there are no additional restrictions on what a member function can return vs regular function.

Though in your code example `func()` cannot return object of type `B` as it is not defined there yet. You would need to move `class B` definition before `class A` or use forward declaration and then only declare (not define) `A::func` there, and then you can define (implement) it only after `class B` definition:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    B func( int x ); // declared
    B func2() { return B{}; } // this would not compile with forward declaration of B
};

class B {
};

// this definition must see class B defined, not forward declared
B A::func( int x ) 
{
    return B{};
}
```

Additional details about forward declaration can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the compiler knows about `B` before your declaration for `func`.  Either move the definition for `class B {};` above `class A`, or forward declare `B` by writing `class B;` before `class A`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is allowed as long as you put the classes in order. Currently, your example does not work. It is:

```
class A
{
    int a,b;
public:
    B func(int x); // func returns type B which is another class
};

class B
{
};
```

You either need to put class B before A, like this:

```
class B
{
};
class A
{
    int a,b;
public:
    B func(int x); // func returns type B which is another class
};
```

Or Forward declare it:

```
class B; //Forward Declaration.
class A
{
    int a,b;
public:
    B func(int x); // func returns type B which is another class
};

class B
{
};
```

Otherwise, your code should work.